# JPA relationship for existing table and parent table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table which has a foreign key relationship with an existing table and its child table.  The parent table exists before the child table as is populated by a liquibase script.   The tables are as as follows:

```
  person
    id int primary key,
    name varchar2(25) not null,
    age int not null

 child
    id int primary key,
    name varchar2(25) not null,
    person_id_fk int references person(id)
```

Is it possible to omit the relationship between the person and child entities and only specify the foreign key in the child entity class. Since the Person table has already been populated, I don't need to save rows to it. I simply want to enforce the relationship by the database tables definitions and have the dbms enforce it.  In other words, when I save the child, I only want the dbms to enforce the integrity constraints if they are violated.  Is this possible to simply express the entity like shown below and not as a @ManyToOne in the child table?

```
 @Entity
 class Child {
    int id;
    String name;
    int personFk; // foreign key in the person table.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply added a field to the object representing the foreign key relationship, as in my child object and enforced the foreign key relationship at the database level and I encountered no problems